# How to modify the touchscreen driver on android to get automatic fast screen touching?

Tags: android, c, linux, linux-kernel, android-kernel

My device is huawei p7,the app would detect the root permission,so i want to midify the ts driver to get automatic fast screen touching..
The ts driver is
https://github.com/Kostyan-nsk/hwp6s-kernel/blob/5.1.1/drivers/huawei/drivers/touchscreen/ts/huawei_touchscreen.c
The main function is started by the 1118 line.
I had added

```
finger->fingers[id].status = TS_FINGER_PRESS;
TS_LOG_DEBUG("down: id is %d\n", id);
finger_num++;
input_report_abs(input_dev, ABS_MT_PRESSURE, 1);             
input_report_abs(input_dev, ABS_MT_POSITION_X, 500);             
input_report_abs(input_dev, ABS_MT_POSITION_Y, 500);             
input_report_abs(input_dev, ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID, id);             
input_mt_sync(input_dev);
finger->fingers[id].status = TS_FINGER_RELEASE;
TS_LOG_DEBUG("up: id is %d\n", id);
input_mt_sync(input_dev);
```

to the end of the 1143 line,but it only change the coordinate and touch once,even though I had add a 'for' cycle.
Please help me about how to get the screen touch many times in a specific point.

Comment: Have tried to increase the sensitivity of driver by changing configurations via settings without actually changing the driver?

Comment: don't know how to..